# Getting uniqueid of mobile device

Tags: android, ios, react-native

My question is general and not specifically related to react native. I want to get the mobile device's (hardware's) unique id. I came across a react native library that can help me achieve this:
https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid

For android, it retrieves id of the form `dd96dec43fb81c97`.

My **RELATED** questions -

1. How unique is this unique device id: `dd96dec43fb81c97` for android ?
2. Is it possible that 2 devices may have the same 'unique' device ids?
3. After factory reset, does this value change on the device?
4. Can the user of mobile device change this id themselves?
5. What are the other options to get the unique device id? I think MAC address? But I think it is prohibited? Maybe MAC address is too private?

Although I have given reference to react native. But my question is general.

Comment: I would appreciate answers to some/any/all of above related questions

Comment: 1 and 2. It is a 128 bit value which gives 3 x 10^38 possible values. Assuming a reasonable ransom number generator, the chances of a duplicate are basically zero. 3. The Android code seems to use the firebase id, so I would expect it to change if your app was deleted and reinstalled as it will on iOS. 5. Assuming that Android has caught up with ios on this, there is no way to get a lifetime unique device identifier.

Comment: 1. it is a 64bit hex string with your signing key, user and device (FYR: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID)
2. yes, but close to never
3. yes
4. not sure about rooted device. user can re-generate it.
5. IEMI (not all device got phone function), Mac addresses (you can't get them when they are off.). for IOS, idfa + keychain combo is enough(your package is doing it). For Android, no idea.